# Android styling action bar overflow menu?

Tags: android

I am trying to style the overflow menu items on the action bar but so far I've had no luck. I am testing on Android API 21 but my minimum version is set to 17. I am using the theme DeviceDefault. I tried setting the theme to Holo but the action bar disappears completely then. Anyways, here are the styles I'm currently using for the action bar:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo|showTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

</style>

<style name="MyActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient3</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.DeviceDefault.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/gradient1</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ed</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ed</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

So far popupMenuStyle seems to be ignored on API 21 but the action bar background takes effect. What is the correct way of styling the overflow menu for android versions 17 onwards? Also, is it recommended to use DeviceDefault as the theme and if not, is there a reason the Holo theme is making the action bar disappear?

Thank you. I appreciate any help.